# How to copy and paste email list on Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

With Hotmail I could copy and paste email addresses and send. I tried this with the new Outlook and it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have just verified it again and copy paste of the contacts is working fine. Are you facing issues on any specific browser?

I type some email addresses on notepad, did copy and paste in outlook on firefox and it could send email to all address.

Kindly let me know if you are facing issue on any specific browser.

Thanks,
Ankit Mehta

Answer (score 0):

When pasting email addresses in the To field with CTRL-V does not work, try using right mouse, Paste.